# How to get CPU usage on Mac OS X (not use top command)

Tags: macos, operating-system, cpu-usage

I need to collect for CPU usage oftentimes, and the top command costs lots of time (top -F -R -l 1). I also try "sysctl" and "sysctlbyname" but below functions cannot get CPU usage. So, if there is any API or command line

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for programmers.  This question isn't programming related as it stands.  If you can edit to make it programming related (what language, emphasize API requirements) then feel free to flag for moderator attention to reopen.  If you wish to learn about command line applications, feel free to ask about them on [apple.SE].